# Is there a built-in function or plugin to handle date formatting in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, date-formatting

Currently I need to output a date in a: '5 October, 2012' type format. Meaning day-of-month with no leading zeros, space, full month name, comma, space, four-digit year. I need to do this in JavaScript. I have this working but it occurs to me while writing the lengthy code that somebody must've already figured out a better way to do this.

I don't think there is a built in function of JavaScript that formats this exactly how I want. There is just a thing in PHP with `date()`. Is there a plugin for JavaScript that does the same thing?

For the sake of giving a specific example, in this instance I start with a set number of hours into the future that I need to get the date for.

Currently I have:

```
    var myNow = new Date().getTime();
    var myTime = hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var myDate = new Date(myTime + myNow);
    var myDay = myDate.getDate();
    var myMonthNum = myDate.getMonth();
    var myMonth = '';
    var myYear = myDate.getFullYear();

    switch(myMonthNum) {
        case 0:
            myMonth = 'January';
            break;
        ...

    var completeDate = myDate = " " + myMonth + ", " + myYear;
    $('#theEndDate').html(completeDate);
```

Comment: DateJS :) http://www.datejs.com

Comment: DateJS hasn't been updated in almost 5 years.. I'd personally use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) but if you're doing something as simple as that, there shouldn't be any need to load an external library when your short code does exactly what you want.

Comment: Since you know some PHP, check out php.js at phpjs.org.  Here's their JS equivalent of date():  http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380  The site is a good resource for those who know some PHP and struggle to find similar functions in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing built-in for [`Date`objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but there are a bunch of libraries to deal with and format them:

- [date.js](http://www.datejs.com)
- [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)
- [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/)
- [Date](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Native/Date) and [Date.Extras](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Native/Date.Extras) in Mootools
- [Date](http://sugarjs.com/dates) in Sugar
- [Dojo.date](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.date)
- [a few functions](http://www.mochikit.com/doc/html/MochiKit/DateTime.html) in Mochikit
- [DateFormat](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/) (only PHP's `date`)
- [date](http://phpjs.org/functions/date) at php.js
- [DataType](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatype/#dates) in YUI, especially for i18n
- [date-functions.js](https://gist.github.com/xaprb/8492729), used especially by [JQuery datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) plugin

Comment: Related: [Date manipulation libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802861/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You've got some extraneous code that you can clean up:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    today = new Date(),
    completeDate = today.getDate() + " " + months[today.getMonth()] + ", " + today.getFullYear();

$('#theEndDate').html(completeDate);
```

Using a library isn't always the answer, especially if you are only going to use it in one spot.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of date libraries, but if all you want to do is generate one specific format from a date object, it's pretty trivial:

```
var formatDate = (function() {

  var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
      'July','August','September','October','November','December'];

  return function(date) {
    return date.getDate() + ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.getFullYear();
  }
}());

alert(formatDate(new Date())); // 28 September, 2012
```

I think that took less than 5 minutes.

Comment: It is obviously trivial. It was never a question of difficulty or even  handling that one specific scenario. More a point of having to lay it all out every time any date handling is needed gets a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Generally you only want one format for each application, writing a function is pretty simple and can become part of your toolbox. You'll likely spend less time doing that than looking for and evaluating date libraries.