# How to use parseDate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

`variable` currently outputs as `2013-02-05T16:30:01Z`

How do I use parseDate(), to change how the date is formatted?

Comment: @args That's to do with parsing dates. This is about formatting dates.

Comment: @asgs I was unable to find anything helpful, I'll look around though!

Comment: Yes, but it still has certain answers on formatting date strings.

Comment: Which parseDate are you talking about?  That's not a native method of JavaScript at all. So your answer is going to rely on whose `.parseDate` it is you're actually using.

Comment: What is `parseDate()`? And why do you want to use a *parse* function for *formatting*?

Comment: Yes, you might want to tag this JQuery, if it's relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function or plugin to handle date formatting in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632148/is-there-a-built-in-function-or-plugin-to-handle-date-formatting-in-javascript) or [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @Bergi if he's holding a string instead of a date object, he would need to parse it first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the object Date in order to define the Date.

```
var d = new Date('2013-02-05T16:30:01Z');
```

the variable `d` is now a `Date` object you can process all date methods. And I think that parseDate() is a jQuery UI method (`$.datepicker.parseDate`)