# How can I convert a short date to a long date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to convert *04/06/13* (for example) to a long date - *Tue Jun 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)*. How can I do this using Javascript? I know how to convert a long date to a short date - just not the other way round.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [parsing functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) of the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), whose result you then can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString):

```
> new Date("04/06/13").toString()
"Sun Apr 06 1913 00:00:00 GMT+0200" // or something
```

But the parsing is implementation-dependent, and there won't be many engines that interpret your odd `DD/MM/YY` format correctly. If you had used `MM/DD/YYYY`, it probably would be recognized everywhere.

Instead, you want to ensure how it is parsed, so have to do it yourself and feed the single parts into the constructor:

```
var parts = "04/06/13".split("/"),
    date = new Date(+parts[2]+2000, parts[1]-1, +parts[0]);
console.log(date.toString()); // Tue Jun 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: That's strange, because on Chrome v25 "new Date("04/06/13")" evaluates to "Sat Apr 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

Comment: Why is that strange? Date parsing is implementation-dependent by spec, it only needs to recognize ISO8601 and its own `toString` output. I would even have *expected* an odd format like `DD/MM/YY` not to be parsed correctly everywhere.

Comment: I thought that all implementations defaulted to 1900. Hence it was strange or a shock for me to see that this was not the case.

Comment: *don't* use the parsing functionality - it's locale dependent!  Always use the latter form where you pass the year, month and date as numbers.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah, seems I didn't emphazise this enough. Answer updated :-)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! How can I convert this long date back to a short date now?

Comment: You will need to manually construct it again (or use a [library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12632212/1048572)). `Date` objects have useful methods, look into them!

Comment: I've had a look around and can't find anything that will work. I'm trying to use http://momentjs.com for example, and I can't seem to be able to convert the long date to a short one?

Comment: @Bergi NB: `dd/mm/yy` is _not_ an odd format - it's used by most of the world and  it's a damn sight more logical than the US `mm/dd/yy` format!

Comment: @Alnitak: `dd/mm/yyyy` is OK. Yet the confusion with the really odd US format does make it not well-suited for exchanging dates - especially since browsers are not consistent there (and seem to favour the US format). Better would be the international standard `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @Bergi oh, absolutely, everyone should really be using ISO 8601 :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the split method, uses lastIndexof and slice instead, to change the year to ISO8601 format which then gives a non-standard string that is known to be working across browsers, and then uses the [date parsing method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). (assuming a fixed pattern like in question)

However,

> If you want to ensure how it is parsed, you have to do it yourself and
>   feed the single parts into the constructor:

, this would mean using the split method, [see @Bergi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16627218/592253).

```
var string = "04/06/13",
    index = string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
    date = new Date(string.slice(0, index) +  (2000 + parseInt(string.slice(index), 10)));

console.log(date);
```

Output

```
Sat Apr 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dSexM/)

or a further alternative would be to use [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var string = "04/06/13";

console.log(moment(string, "DD/MM/YY").toString());
```

Output

```
Sat Apr 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kGv5s/)

Comment: `"04/06/2013"` is not [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - though the format is known to be working across browsers.

Comment: +1 for Moment.js.  Most reliable way to do this consistently across browsers that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new Date(2013, 06, 04)
```

...or directly using a date string (i.e. a string representing a date as accepted by the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method):

```
new Date("2013/06/04");
```

...or by specifying the different parts of your date, like:

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

You have to take 13 as 2013 otherwise it will take default 1913

```
alert(new Date('04/06/2013'));
```

Comment: Otherwise it could possibly default to 1913